# How can I deploy a Git repository from GitHub to my XAMPP htdocs folder on Windows 10?

Tags: git, github, xampp, windows-10, htdocs

I'm actually making a small project at home and I started using GitHub. I have a website hosted on xampp (windows 10) and I wonder if it's possible to deploy a git repository to my htdocs xampp folder.

Sorry for my bad English, it's not my main language :)

I tried searching online but didn't found anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.